# Exclude Active Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro here. So it gets the sheets names but I want to exclude the active sheet from showing up. I tried doing `i=2`, which works, but I don't want there to be an empty row. Any ideas?

```
Sub GetNames()

    'Headers
    Range("A1").Value = "File Name "
    Range("B1").Value = "Sheet Name "
    Range("C1").Value = "Column Name"

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Cells(i + 1, 2) = Sheets(i).Name
        Cells(i + 1, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim intRow As Long: intRow = 2

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    If Sheets(i).Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
        Cells(intRow, 2) = Sheets(i).Name
        Cells(intRow, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        intRow = intRow + 1
    End If
Next i
```